# reading /proc/meminfo from adobe air android app

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, adb

So if I pop open a command prompt and take a peek at my device's /proc/meminfo, like so:

```
adb shell cat /proc/meminfo
```

I get back what you'd expect - a nice long list of data on the device's RAM usage + capacity. But when I try to read that same location from an adobe air android app, using this basic code:

```
var meminfo:File = new File().resolvePath('/proc/meminfo');
meminfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function(e:Event):void {
    trace(File(e.target).data);
});
meminfo.load();
```

... I get nothing, just an empty ByteArray.

So why can I see the contents of /proc/meminfo from the adb shell, but not from the app? Same goes for other stuff in the /proc/ directory - cpuinfo, for instance. I have no problem loading an xml file from the /etc/ directory, though.

Comment: `/proc` folder is IIRC paravirtual, that is, it exists as a memory location or interface within Linux kernel, thus it's not a normal `File` to be read by loading it as a file. Also, several security measures exist to not allow applications to read system configuration in order to prevent viruses or other malicious code to spoof critical information. There is a known restriction of Adobe Flash Player to not let AS3 code to reach system config on Windows, probably the same security restriction applies here.

Comment: So this is definitely the right answer to my question - but I also came up with a 'solution,' where simply copying that file out somewhere works fine and the copy doesn't appear to have the same access restrictions. Do you want to add your answer and have me mark it correct, or should I self-answer with my solution?

Comment: I think you should better use a self-answer, as this includes your own research and action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that if you copy memtest (or cputest, etc.) out to another location, somewhere a little friendlier to AIR - say, File.documentsDirectory - then everything goes smoothly.

Your code might look a little like this:

```
var meminfo_original:File = new File().resolvePath('/proc/meminfo');
var meminfo_copy:File = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath('meminfo.txt');
meminfo_original.copyTo(meminfo_copy, true);
meminfo_copy.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function(e:Event):void    {
    trace(File(e.target).data.toString());
});
meminfo_copy.load();
```